# How to remove parent property and function with babel transform?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Say I have this code

```js
import someOtherFunction from 'whatever'

function testFunction(hello) {
  return someOtherFunction(hello.world.name)
}
```

I want to transform this to something like:

```js
import someOtherFunction from 'whatever'

function testFunction(hello) {
  return world.name
}
```

Basically, I want to remove the `hello` property and the function wrapping them.

What I have achieved so far:

```js
transformSync(code, {
  plugins: [
    function customPlugin() {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Identifier(path) {
            if (path.isIdentifier({ name: 'world' })) {
              if (
                path.parentPath.isMemberExpression()
                && path.parentPath.get('object').isIdentifier({ name: 'hello' })
              ) {
                path.parentPath.name = '' // remove hello property?
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Changing the name of the identifier won't cut it. You actually have to modify the tree itself by removing those nodes that you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replaceWith()`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#replacing-a-node) to achieve transform you need:

```js
transformSync(code, {
  plugins: [
    function customPlugin() {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Identifier(path) {
            if (path.isIdentifier({ name: 'world' })) {
              if (
                path.parentPath.isMemberExpression()
                && path.parentPath.get('object').isIdentifier({ name: 'hello' })
              ) {
                   const objectPath = path.parentPath.parentPath.get('object');
                   const callExpressionPath = path.parentPath.parentPath.parentPath;
            
                   objectPath.replaceWith(path.node);
                   callExpressionPath.replaceWith(path.parentPath.parentPath.node);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

Here is playground: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/25cddb49aaa339ac43f9ffe379b503ac/9f7c8c2f8e39f5164d39187a84fb8eb481f7780c

You can also achieve it in a much simpler way, with the tool I'm working on: [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout). The transform will look this way:

```js
export const replace = () => ({
    '__(hello.world.name)': 'world.name',
});
```

Here is playground: https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/023465614b7ca1194ba6f3b22be3af7c/a17bc62c3cf10f823ba007d759ec3de3298b4a2d

```js
const source = `
    import someOtherFunction from 'whatever'

    function testFunction(hello) {
        return someOtherFunction(hello.world.name)
    }
`;

const {code} = putout(source, {
    plugins: [
        ['remove-hello', {
            report: () => `Remove 'hello'`,
            replace: () => ({
                '__(hello.world.name)': 'world.name',
            }),
        }]
    ]
 });
 
 console.log(code);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@putout/bundle@1.7/bundle/putout-iife.js"></script>
```